# msgsnd no permission error

Tags: c, unix, message-queue, linux-capabilities

I want to send messages between two processes. But I get a `EACCES` error when im trying to send a message with `msgsnd()`

**Creating the message queue**

```
const char* MSG_QUEUE = "/tmp/msg_queue";

int file = open(MSG_QUEUE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0755);
close(file);
key_t key = ftok(MSG_QUEUE, 1);
errno = 0;
msg_queue = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT);
if(msg_queue == -1) {
    M_DEBUG("Error %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

**message struct**

```
struct feld_msg_s {
    long id;
    char mtext[5];
};
```

**sending a message**

```
struct feld_msg_s a_msg = {1, "Test"};
errno = 0;
int ret = msgsnd(msg_queue, &a_msg, sizeof(a_msg.mtext), 0);
if(ret == -1) {
    if(errno == EACCES) {
        printf("\r\n NO PERMISSION\r\n");
    } else {
        printf("msgsnd ERROR!: %s\r\n", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

in the manpage of msgsnd is written

> **EACCES** The calling process does not have read permission on the message queue, and does not have the CAP_IPC_OWNER capability.

so I've added the following capabilities with the `setcap` command

```
sudo setcap CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_IPC_OWNER+epi /home/mvollmer/build-APP-Desktop_Qt_5_6_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/APP
```

I've checked with `getcap` if the application got the capabilities. It's fine. But I still receive the No Permission Error.

When execute the application with root rights, its working!

One thing is very strange, altough msgget was succesfull `ipcs` dont show any message queues.

So where is my fault?

I'm using Linux Mint

**Additional Question**: Is is possible to use another datatype then char in the msg struct or is a message restricted to strings?

Comment: try this  `msg_queue = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT | 0666)`

Comment: with this i get an EACCES when `msgget` is called. When i delete the file `/tmp/msg_queue` `msgget` and `msgsnd` is succesful...Thanks! But why?!

Comment: This is strange.. it works now every time.. After deleting the file and add | 0666 to the msgget flag.
and the message queue is shown with ipcs now!
Thanks you very much

Comment: You're welcome. This was a matter of setting the right permissions on the message queue. 0666 means read/write is allowed to all.

Comment: You did not allow *group* and *other* to write to this file.

Comment: @mvollmer After you deleted the file, `ftok()` returned a different key.  So you were creating and accessing an IPCS message queue using a different key and therefore getting a different message queue ID.  Unless you've rebooted, `ipcs -a` will probably show your previous message queue, with its `000` permissions, still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the man page.  Per [the POSIX `msgget()` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/msgget.html):

> ***SYNOPSIS***
>
> ```
> #include <sys/msg.h>
>
> int msgget(key_t key, int msgflg); [Option End]
> ```
>
> ***DESCRIPTION***
>
> ...
>
> - The low-order 9 bits of **msg_perm.mode** shall be set to the low-order 9 bits of *msgflg*.

Thus, this code

```
msg_queue = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT);
```

has the "low-order 9 bits of *msgflg*" all set to zero. Thus the message queue mode is also all `0` - no permissions for anyone.